# How i change my website address through .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

**How i change my website address through .htaccess
my url structure is :

```
http://mydomain.com/portfolio.php?page=3
```

where portfolio.php is a page and active navigation for page id is 3
and i use to create this url to seo friendly like

```
http://mydomain.com/page/portfolio/
```

but when create this id is not working or page shows internal error.
please help to resolve this issue, i can't find anywhere this issue solve.**

Comment: show some `.htaccess` code you've tried and others may correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/portfolio/$ /portfolio.php?page=$1 [L]
```

you can access `page 3` by visiting this URL

```
http://mydomain.com/3/portfolio/
```

**OR**

Just change `RewriteRule` to

```
RewriteRule ^page(.*)/portfolio/$ /portfolio.php?page=$1 [L]
```

now `page 3` will be on

```
http://mydomain.com/page3/portfolio/
```

Comment: Sorry but this not working its says "Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster."